# Magento - Different css for different email template

Tags: magento-1.9, email-templates

I need to hide the email header only for order email. How would you achieve that in **Magento 1**?

One thing that I have in mind is to have different class in the `<body>` tag. But is it possible for the email templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can remove header for order email in

```
_appName_/app/locale/en_US/template/email/sales/order_new.phtml
```

(**order_new_guest.phtml** if enable guest checkout)

then just remove this line code

```
{{template config_path="design/email/header"}}
```